# which journals accept an original idea on AI based face recognition tool as a conceptual paper

Tags: research, face-recognition, journalism

I have an original idea/concept for a new face recognition AI based tool. I do not want to patent it but wish to publish it as a conceptual paper, that is to share the original concept. which journals allows this kind of conceptual paper

Comment: You mean to explain the idea, without a practical implementation and comparison with the SOTA?

Comment: @LucaAnzalone YES

Comment: Maybe the [Frontiers in AI](https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/artificial-intelligence) journal. Have a check, I'm not so sure

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your response.